# I cannot create new account

Tags: magento-1.9

I cannot create new account. Please help finding the file path to register in the Porto theme (cannot change)

Comment: What exactly happens if you try to create an account? Why do you need a file path to create a new account? Or are you looking for the **URL** to register? That's `/customer/account/register`

Comment: cannot create new account.

Answer (score 0):

```
1)Log into the magento back-end admin

2)Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu

3)Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED

4)Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.

5)Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.
```

and you will come to know which phtml is call.

Comment: how to call phtml?

Comment: till now what you try please explain me in detail